# Problems with fancybox 2.1.5 and ie7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, fancybox

I'm using the fancybox with TYPO3 v6.1.5. Everything is fine, only the ie7 doesn't show any popup for an image or an iframe. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    prevEffect : 'fade',
    nextEffect : 'fade',
    fitToView : false, // to show videos in their own size
    scrolling: 'no', // don't show scrolling bars in fancybox        
    minWidth : 450,
    maxWidth : 600,
    mouseWheel : 'true',
     beforeShow : function() {
       this.title = (this.title ? '' + this.title + '' : '') + ' (' + (this.index + 1) + '/' + this.group.length + ')';
    },
    helpers : {
      title : { type : 'outside' },
      overlay: { locked: false },
      // buttons : {}
    },
  });
  // iFrame Content
  $("a[target=fancybox]").fancybox({       
    // ohne untere Navigationszeile
    // autoSize : false,
    width : 600,
    height : 340,
    type : 'iframe',
    iframe: {
      scrolling : 'no',
      preload   : 'false'
    },      
    helpers : {
      title : { type : 'outside' },
      overlay: { locked: false },
      // buttons : {}
    },        
  });
});
```

The doctype is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="de" lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Thanks for any hints
Thomas

Comment: do you really need the `<?xml` declaration on the top of your document? are you rendering a regular html page or a xml page? maybe the xhtml declaration would be enough

Comment: I changed the doctype to <!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="de" lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> without success. I'm rendering a regualr html page.

Comment: try also removing the last trailing commas `,` after `{ locked: false },` and the closing curly bracket of the `helpers` option `},` ... IE is pickier than most browsers. You shouldn't have them without a following option.

Comment: thanks a lot for the hint, now everything ist fine.